# Accessible and Modifiable data?

Tags: java, class, oop

what is the difference between accessible and modifiable data in the variable grade in terms of accessibility from outside the class?

This is my code where i'm calling grade method from outside the class:

```
package studenttester;

public class student {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String grade;
    private double average;
    private boolean disability;
    
    
    private void printStudentInfo(){ //Data Encapsulation is methods of the public interface provide access to private data, while hiding implementation. 

        System.out.println("Name: "+name+",Age: "+age+",Grade: "+grade+",Average: "+average +" Disability: "+disability);
    } 
    
    public void setGrade(String newGrade){
        grade=newGrade;
    }
    
    public String getGrade(){
        return grade;
    }
 }
    public class StudentTester{
public static void main(String[] args){
       student S1 = new student(); 
       student S2 = new student(); 

       S1.setGrade("11");
       System.out.println("Student one: " +S1.getGrade()+", Student two: "+S2.getGrade());

       /* The instance variables are name, age, grade, average, disability and those are the variables that the object S2 contains. The object’s attributes are : name, age, grade, average, disability. 

       S1 attributes values : name: null , age:0, grade:"11", average : 0.0, disability: false
       S2 attributes values : name: null , age:0, grade:null, average : 0.0, disability: false */

}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

accessible data means you can only access .we can you only view or access the data it can not be modified or changed

whereas modifiable can be modified or can be changed.

you can say accessible data are constant and modifiable data are variables

Comment: You cannot say that accessible data are constants and modifiable data are variables. What if I have a variable that I declare as final? What if I have a constant that I declare as public? The main issue here concerns access modifiers, and your answer fails to address that concept at all.

Comment: this was just a an explanation for noobies there are many thing that can be done

Comment: Your answer is factually wrong and you seek to excuse its wrongness because it's "for noobies?" Access modifiers don't work one way for beginners and a different way for experienced programmers. To top it off, you gave zero explanation of the issue at the heart of the question.

Comment: we can fight on this all day..... that its wrong or right but if you understand the concept that's all .... getter method is use to get the value and setter method is you to set the value that's all in it

Answer (score 1):

Grade is `private` so in terms of *direct* accessibility outside of the student class, it is not accessible. So if we had a variable s1 of Student type, trying `s1.grade` will not work. Although, since we have a `public` getter method `getGrade`, it actually is accessible by other classes. Same goes for modification, so no `s1.grade = "11";` outside the class but you can do `s1.setGrade("11")`.